# Arduino Pubsubclient cleansessionflag = false not queuing messages when the device is offline

Tags: arduino, message-queue, mqtt

I am using arduino zero(samd21) with wifi101 module(atwinc1500)with the library Imory pubsubclient library forked from @knolleary to do a MQTT connection with IBM Bluemix broker.

I am able to publish and subscribe to messages asuccessfully, however, I need to queue the IOTF commands to receive the commands sent to my device when it is offline. I understand that cleansession flag should be unset while connecting to the brokerto queue the commands when the device is offline.

Here is my code snippet:

```
 while(!Org_Client.connected())
         {
              SerialUSB.println("Connecting to MQTT server");
                if (Org_Client.connect(MQTT::Connect(Org_ClientID).unset_clean_session().set_auth(authMethod,token)))
                {
                    SerialUSB.println("Connected to MQTT server");
                  Org_Client.subscribe(MQTT::Subscribe().add_topic(subtopic1,0));
                   Org_Client.subscribe(MQTT::Subscribe().add_topic(subtopic2,0));
                   Org_Client.subscribe(MQTT::Subscribe().add_topic(subtopic3,0));
                   Org_Client.subscribe(MQTT::Subscribe().add_topic(subtopic4,0));

}
}
```

//subtopic1,subtopic2,subtopic3,subtopic4 are my subscription topics and 0 corresponds t QOS 0.

However, my device isn't receiving the queued commands as expected. Am I missing on something?

Answer (score 0):

Messages subscribed to at QoS 0 won't be queued because the broker will try to deliver at the time of publishing then throw it away.

The pubsub client can subscribe at QoS 0 & 1. Try subscribing at QoS 1

Comment: Hi, I tried using QOS 1 but I keep getting the commands again and again everytime the device comes online even after I process the commands and send the notify the server. I could see that the server identifies the command has been processed at the IBM dashboard, but I still get the commands, I am sure the same command is repeating because the requisition Id which is identical for the commands.